# Password Reset Token provider in .NET 6 console app - IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider not found

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, console-application

I am attempting to create an email with password reset for my users and I cannot figure out why I receive this error: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered.

Here is my Program.cs :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
         .Build();

        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        var connectionStrings = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
        var messagingConnectionString = connectionStrings.GetValue<string>("Messaging");

        AgentConfigDTO appSettingsDTO = new AgentConfigDTO()
        {
           ....
        };

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings.ToString(),
            sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 5,
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorNumbersToAdd: null);
            }
            ));

        // Register UserManager & RoleManager
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            options =>
            {
                options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
            }
            )
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, UserStore<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddTransient<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var optionsBuilderApplication = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var _applicationContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilderApplication.UseSqlServer(connectionStrings.ToString()).Options);
     
        IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_applicationContext);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store, null, new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>(), null, null, null, null, serviceProvider, null);

        // UserManager & RoleManager require logging and HttpContext dependencies
        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        new ReportAgent(appSettingsDTO, messagingConnectionString, userManager).RunAsConsole(args);
    }
}
```

ReportAgent.cs

```
 public void RunAsConsole(string[] args)
        {
             \\calls RunSystemJob method             
        }

protected void RunSystemJob(string jobName, string parameters, int commandTimeOutSecs, AgentConfigDTO _appConfig)
        {
            IReportJob job = null;

            switch (jobName.ToLower())
            {
                case "checkpasswords":
                    job = new CheckPasswords(_context, parameters, _applicationContext, _userManager, _appConfig);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Cannot execute system job {jobName} as it cannot be found.");
            }

            if (job != null)
            {
                job.CommandTimeOut = commandTimeOutSecs;
                job._appConfig = _appConfig;
                job.Run();
            }
        }
```

CheckPasswords.cs

```
public void Run()
        {
            CheckingPasswords();
        }

        public void CheckingPasswords()
        {
            try
            {               
                var date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
                var userList = _applicationContext.Users.Where(t => t.PasswordExpiry != null && t.PasswordExpiry <= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3) && t.Deleted == false && t.PortalAccessEnabled == true).ToList();

                if (userList.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Create email
                    foreach (var user in userList)
                    {
                        // Lock user out of the account
                        user.PortalAccessEnabled = false;
                        _applicationContext.Update(user);
                        _applicationContext.SaveChanges();

                        //Create email

                        var code = _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user).ToString(); // HERE IT THROWS THE EXCEPTION
                        var url = .
                        var callbackUrl = url.Replace("[[id]]", user.Id).Replace("[[code]]", code);

                        Email email = new()
                        {
                            ID = 0,
                            From = _appConfig.DefaultFromEmail,
                            To = user.Email,
                            IsHTML = true,
                            QueuedAt = DateTime.Now,
                            SendAt = DateTime.Now,
                            Subject = Core.Resource.Portal.Pages.Common_PortalName + " - " + Core.Resource.Portal.Pages.User_ResetPassword_EmailSubject,
                            Created = DateTime.Now,
                            Body = string.Format(Core.Resource.Portal.Pages.User_ResetPassword_EmailBody, callbackUrl),
                            TrackingID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Status = 1 //Pending
                        };
                        _dbContext.Add(email);
                        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've also tried manually adding in the Token Provider but that didn't make any difference:

```
 var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(IdentityRole<string>), services);
 identityBuilder.AddTokenProvider("Default", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>));
 services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!